# Convert data send from server through POST/GET to jquery function

Tags: jquery, json

How to convert data to Integer which came with GET/POST from server to jquery function.

**1)** Those lines belong to server , and they are send to jquery script

```
line = json.dumps([1])
       return line
```

**2)** This little code returns fetched result as json from the server , well at least i think its a json objects.

```
function lol() {
   $.getJSON("http://help.me.plz:12345/test",function(result){
       return result
   });
}
```

**3)** So how do i convert value which comes  from lol() to int ?

```
while (data.length < totalPoints) {
            var prev = data.length > 0 ? data[data.length - 1] : 50;
            var y = lol();
            data.push(y);
```

Debug : Thats what i basically get from firebug

> Headers Response  HTML [1]    <--- SO it is send

```
Response Headersview source
Date    Tue, 03 May 2011 09:11:05 GMT
Content-Length  3
Content-Type    text/html
Server  TwistedWeb/8.1.0
```

Its a dump of the last list i need to get, but i get undefined instead of numbers.

```
[[0, undefined], [1, undefined], [2, undefined]  ....
```

I tried to fetch content with $.ajax() , i tried to use  ***parseInt()***  on lol , basically on everything .... I am kind of lost :D  I am sure it is easy . Yet my stupidity makes me ask for help ....

Comment: The problem you're having is not data conversion.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks that  "f@#%k me please" in the getJson url is a little crass?

Comment: Sorry for the crass url =). The only thing that came to my mind at 6 in the morning. And thnaks Ignasio you are right . That was not a data conversion problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous by default, so you can't return the value in a function. You'd have to do something like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://help.me.plz:12345/test", function(result){
  var y = result; //Now we don't call lol()
  while (data.length < totalPoints) {
            var prev = data.length > 0 ? data[data.length - 1] : 50;
            data.push(y);
    ...
  }     
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thx Edgar . You are exactly right. I should have learned javascript more properly before doing something like that =). Wasted so much time on this. Should have asked from the begining.